# getuikit link not working in dropdown

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, getuikit

I'm working on a .NET core 2.1 mvc app. I have a dropdown in a tab menu. The dropdown functions properly, but when I click an item in the dropdown, I'm not redirected to the appropriate page. However, if I right click and select open in new tab etc., the link behaves properly.

markup:

```
      <ul uk-tab>
         <li>
         <a href="#">Add Mfr/Rep <span class="uk-margin-small-left" uk-icon="icon: triangle-down"></span></a>
         <div uk-dropdown="mode: click">
            <ul class="uk-nav uk-dropdown-nav">
                <li>
                    <a asp-action="AddManufacturer" asp-controller="Manufacturers">Add Manufacturer</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a asp-controller="Sources" asp-action="AddSource">Add Rep</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>  
</ul>
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this:

```
<li>
   <a href "/Manufacturers/AddManufacturer">Add Manufacturer</a>
</li>
<li>
   <a href "/Sources/AddSource">Add Rep</a>
</li>
```

Comment: I have tried that, but still no dice. I just find it odd that I can right click and navigate to the page, but nothing happens when left clicking on a link like you normally would.